# Woocommerce change shopping cart icon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I change the Woocommerce shopping cart icon? I am using theme Ellie and their shopping cart icon is confusing, only a circle. So how could I change that?

Any help is much appreciated!

[Cart icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkLZM.jpg)

https://senjacosmetics.com/shop/

Answer (score 1):

You can change the cart icon by CSS by below code in CSS,

```html
.site-header-cart .cart-toggler .cart-contents {
 content: '';
 background: url('URL_TO_YOUR_CART_IMAGE') no-repeat center center;
 background-size: contain;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 margin: -2px -4px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Replace URL_TO_YOUR_CART_IMAGE with the URL to your cart icon.

Answer (score 1):

Make it easier without the use of images. Add a pseudo class :before like this:

Remove border:

```
.site-header-cart .cart-toggler .cart-contents {border:0px;}
```

then add:

```
.site-header-cart .cart-toggler .cart-contents:before { 
content: "\f07a";
font-family: FontAwesome!important;
}
```

Add this to your Child theme or go to your Customizer and add it to Extra CSS section

Comment: Awesome, I tried the last suggestion and it worked. :) Maybe later I will try to change the icon.

Comment: Pleasure to help, but wasn't changing the icon the question?

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following code will help : Please check the screenshot[image]

```
.site-header-cart .cart-toggler .cart-contents:after {
    content: "";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    margin-left: 14px;
}

.site-header-cart .cart-toggler .cart-contents .count {
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
```

Comment: Why use the :after pseudo ? and then add extra margin?

Comment: @Solomax, using before will not achieving the exact design shown in screenshot. You can use my code in Stylebot, to understand. Any problem let me know.